# Function to return information in a custom object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a function that iterates through all HDD's on a computer, and returns information about those drives and their mapping to physical drives in an array.

I would like this function to return the information in a custom object.

Here is the function:

```ps
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
##  FUNCTION.......:  Get-HDDInfo
##  PURPOSE........:  
##  REQUIREMENTS...:  
##  NOTES..........:  
##--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Get-HDDInfo {
    [CmdletBinding()]
        Param([Parameter(Mandatory = $True,
            ValueFromPipeLine = $True,
            Position = 0)]
            [String[]]$ComputerName
        )#END: Param
    $W32_DD = @(gwmi Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName $ComputerName)
    $Array = @()

    $W32_DD | foreach { 
        $query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" `
        + $_.DeviceID + "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskPartition" 
        $Array += $_.Name
        $Array += $_.Model
        <#
        $obj = New-Object PSObject
        $obj.PSObject.typenames.insert(0,'JoeIT.Custom.SystemInfo')
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name `
            "PDCaption" -Value $_.Name
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name `
            "PDModel" -Value $_.Model
        $Array += $obj
        #>
        Get-WmiObject -Query $query | foreach { 

            $Array += $_.Name
            $Array += $_.Description 
            $Array += $_.PrimaryPartition

            #$obj = New-Object PSObject
            <#
            $obj.PSObject.typenames.insert(0,'JoeIT.Custom.SystemInfo')
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name `
                        "DPName" -Value $_.Name
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name `
                        "DPDescription" -Value $_.Description
            $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name `
                        "DPPrimary" -Value $_.PrimaryPartition
            #>
            $query2 = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" `
            + $_.DeviceID + "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_LogicalDisk" 

            Get-WmiObject -Query $query2 | ForEach {
            $Array+= $_.Name
            $Used = [math]::round($_.Size/1024/1024/1024,0)
            $Free = [math]::round($_.FreeSpace/1024/1024/1024,0)
            $Array += [String]$Used +"GB"
            $Array += [String]$Free +"GB"
            #Return $Array;
            #$Array = $Null
            }

            <#
            $Array += $obj
            $obj = $Null
            #>
        }#END: Get-WmiObject -Query
    }#END: $W32_DD | foreach
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ##  Store results in custom Object
    ##----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Return $Array
}#END: Function Get-HDDInfo
```

The stuff that is commented out is from my attempts to get the information into a custom object. Maybe I'm just a bit burnt out, but I just can't seem to make this work right. As you see it, the commented out code tries to overwrite named properties - I knew that when I wrote it, but for some reason I expected it to work anyway ;)

Maybe I shouldn't work three weeks without a day off, but my brain just isn't letting me solve this problem.

What I want is to be able to do something like this:

```
$test = (get-hddinfo $SVR01)
$test.PhysicalDrive1
$test.Partition1
$test.DriveLetter1
$test.TotalSize1
$test.FreeSpace1
```

This would query a computer named SVR01, and write out the first physical HDD, the first logical partition of that drive, the assigned drive letter, total size of the disk, and free space on the disk.

I could then do something like

```
$test.PhysicalDrive2
$(same code here for the second physical drive)
```

What the hell am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
        Param([Parameter(Mandatory = $True,
            ValueFromPipeLine = $True,
            Position = 0)]
            [String[]]$ComputerName
        )
    $W32_DD = @(gwmi Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName $ComputerName)

    $a = new-object  System.Object
    $sc3 = 1
    $sc2 = 1
    $sc1 = 1
    $W32_DD | foreach { 
        $query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" `
        + $_.DeviceID + "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskPartition" 

        $a | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name DiskDriveName$sc1 -value $_.Name
        $a | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name DiskDriveModel$sc1 -value $_.Model       

        Get-WmiObject -Query $query | foreach { 

            $a | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name PartitionName$sc2 -value $_.Name
            $a | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name PartitionDescription$sc2 -value $_.Description
            $a | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name PrimaryPartition$sc2 -value $_.PrimaryPartition

            $query2 = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" `
            + $_.DeviceID + "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_LogicalDisk" 


            Get-WmiObject -Query $query2 | ForEach {

            $a | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name LogicalDiskName$sc3 -value $_.Name           

            $Used = [math]::round($_.Size/1024/1024/1024,0)
            $Free = [math]::round($_.FreeSpace/1024/1024/1024,0)

            $a | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name UsedSpace$sc3 -value $([String]$Used +"GB")
            $a | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name FreeSpace$sc3 -value $([String]$Free +"GB")

            $sc3++
            }
           $sc2++
          }       
       $sc1++
    }

    Return $a
```

Comment: Ok, now that I've tested it, this is not returning correct information on remote machines in the object.

Weirdly wrong too, like I have no idea where it's getting the info from. It returns the correct info for DiskDriveName, DiskDriveModel, but falls apart after that, it looks like it is getting information from the local machine.

Is my GWMI -query syntax wrong or what?

Comment: @JoeG yes, it can be, I hadn't test it but also the nested `get-wmiobject` need the `-computername` parameter...

Comment: Yeah I just figured out that was missing :). Thanks man! I need a vacation, I'm missing obvious stuff now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, it's not exactly what you want but it gives you a way to do it :

```
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
##  FUNCTION.......:  Get-HDDInfo 
##  PURPOSE........:   
##  REQUIREMENTS...:   
##  NOTES..........:   
##-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Function Get-HDDInfo
{ 
  [CmdletBinding()] 
  Param([Parameter(Mandatory = $True, ValueFromPipeLine = $True, Position = 0)] 
        [String[]]$ComputerName)#END: Param 



  $W32_DD = @(gwmi Win32_DiskDrive -ComputerName $ComputerName) 
  $ArrayofPD = @() 

  foreach ($dd in $W32_DD)
  {  
    $query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + $dd.DeviceID + "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_DiskPartition"  

    # create a new physical disc object
    $PDobj = New-Object PSObject 
    $PDobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PDCaption" -Value $dd.Name 
    $PDobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PDModel" -Value $dd.Model 

    $ArrayofLD = @()
    $diskParts = Get-WmiObject -Query $query
    foreach ($diskPart in $diskParts)
    {  
      # create a new logical disc object
      $LDobj = New-Object PSObject 
      $LDobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DPName" -Value $diskPart.Name 
      $LDobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DPDescription" -Value $diskPart.Description 
      $LDobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DPPrimary" -Value $diskPart.PrimaryPartition 

      $query2 = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" + $diskPart.DeviceID + "'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_LogicalDisk"  

      $LogicalDisk = Get-WmiObject -Query $query2
      if ($LogicalDisk -ne $null)
      {
        $LDobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LGName" -Value $LogicalDisk.Name
        $Used = [math]::round($LogicalDisk.Size/1024/1024/1024,0) 
        $Free = [math]::round($LogicalDisk.FreeSpace/1024/1024/1024,0) 
        $LDobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "UsedSpace" -Value $([String]$Used +"GB")
        $LDobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FreeSpace" -Value $([String]$Free +"GB")
      } 
      $ArrayofLD += $LDobj
    }
    $PDobj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "LogicalDisks" -Value $ArrayofLD 

    $ArrayofPD += $PDobj
  }

  ##---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  ##  Store results in custom Object 
  ##---------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Return $ArrayofPD 
}#END: Function Get-HDDInfo 

Clear-Host
$a = Get-HDDInfo localhost
$a
```

Dot source the function for me it gives :

```
PS C:\Users\JPB\Documents> $a = Get-HDDInfo localhost
PS C:\Users\JPB\Documents> $a

PDCaption                                     PDModel                                       LogicalDisks                                 
---------                                     -------                                       ------------                                 
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0                            ST9500420AS                                   {@{DPName=Disque n° 0, partition n° 0; DPD...
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1                            ST932042 3AS USB Device                       {@{DPName=Disque n° 1, partition n° 0; DPD...
```

And :

```
PS C:\Users\JPB\Documents> $a[0].LogicalDisks

DPName                                        DPDescription                                                                     DPPrimary
------                                        -------------                                                                     ---------
Disque n° 0, partition n° 0                   Système de fichiers installable                                                        True
Disque n° 0, partition n° 1                   Système de fichiers installable                                                        True
```